# Need to apply a condition on my dataframe according to the values of one specific column and then apply a function

Tags: python, loops, dataframe

I have a function ready to use to find the Nearest Neighbor. The issue that I have is I need to call this function based on one column condition of the data frame. The column is the ITC code which is the product code of the companies. I want the nearest neighbor to give me 10 results when first 8 digits product code matches for the companies then search in the companies when first 7 digits matches, then for first 6 digits and so on.

Some of the columns of my dataframe look like

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: What have you tried until now? Where are coming up with a problem?

Comment: Actually, I am new to coding, so I don't know how to exactly start to achieve this. But I have tried converting the ITC code column to string and get the digits by its index, then I want to know how to compare those with other values of ITC code.

Comment: Ok. Add your dataframes as code instead of image. You are actively not helping people find a solution. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve .